# Why is my UIImageView blurry when I put it on my storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, ios7

I have an image of an arrow that is 20x36px (10x18pt) and when I select a UIImageView, drag it onto my view controller then set the image, it's always blurry. I'm only including the @2x in my project as it's an iOS 7 only one, but I just can't see why it's so blurry.

Picture:

[image]

It might be hard to tell unless you zoom in, but there's some ugly aliasing going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running the app in the simulator, you can use the "Color Misaligned Images" in the Debug menu. Images coloured yellow are stretched, and images coloured magenta have sub pixel alignment problems.

In this case it looks like the UIImageView's dimensions don't match your image's dimensions, causing the UIImageView to stretch the image. You can do one of two things to ensure that stretching doesn't occur:

1. Make sure your UIImageView's dimensions match your UIImage's. If you're using auto layout, make sure that you only have one horizontal position constraint and one vertical position constraint, and your UIImageView should size to it's intrinsic content size (i.e., the size of the image). If you have size constraints or more than one position constraint in either dimension, those constraints will force the UIImageView to a particular size, which may be different than the size of the image.
2. Set the UIImageView's content mode to a content mode that will not stretch the image, such as Center (`UIViewContentModeCenter`).

Comment: Is there a way to set them to unstretched?

Comment: Just make sure your UIImageView's width and height is the same as the image that you're putting in it.

Comment: What if it's @2x and say, 37px wide?

Comment: Then I would edit the image in an image editor and add 1 pixel of padding to make it an even number of pixels wide.

Comment: @2x images should always be an even number of pixels in both dimensions.  If you use an app like Resizer (by Bonobo), you will get warnings if you use odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I've put the two arrows side by side and added auxiliary lines. The left arrow is vertically stretched by two pixels:

[image]

The width is the same.